# BackBone events don't get fired on a CodeMirror textarea

Tags: events, backbone.js

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({    
   events: {
      "keypress #editor": "updateContent",    
   },

   updateContent: function(ev) {
      # Update model    
   } 
});
```

I've applied a applied a keypress event on a textarea with id `editor`. Eventually this code works, but after transforming the textarea with CodeMirror a  keypress won't fire an event.
Although the the textarea with id `editor` still extists. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are trying to format your code from textarea by CodeMirror, it oveflows the textarea. So, you are typing in it's wrapper, not in your textarea. You should handle CodeMirror's wrapper to get `keypress` event.

Try something like:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editor"));
var View = Backbone.View.extend({    
   events: {
      "keypress .CodeMirror": "updateContent" 
   },

   updateContent: function() {
      console.log(editor.getValue());
   } 
});
```